# i am receiving error while making connection of mysql database(phpmyadmin) to node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
{ 
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/ubuntu/workspace/proj/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/ubuntu/workspace/proj/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:23)
    at Connection.connect (/home/ubuntu/workspace/proj/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/proj/app.js:12:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Timeout.Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:604:10)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true }
```

[IDE Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jCT9.png)

Comment: Are you sure that your DB is on port 3306 and not 8889?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your database is not running on port 3306.

Try and find out the port number and add the port attribute so your code is like this:

```
var db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "udit1",
    port: YOUR_PORT_NUMBER_HERE
});
```